# Windows password does not work for Powershell Credential Request

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, authentication, credentials

I am aware I can set up Powershell credentials [Get-Credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.3) for my own scripts. But when I use the following command [Get a SQL Server instance on a computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/get-sqlinstance?view=sqlserver-ps) in a PS terminal:

```
Get-SqlInstance -Credential laptop-ql9k5dk6\david -ServerInstance "laptop-ql9k5dk6\sqlexpress2"
```

I expect that I am going to be asked for my Windows password.

Here is my thinking:

Logging in to my SQL Server instance (`laptop-ql9k5dk6\david`) via MS SQL Server Management Studio (using Windows Authentication) uses my already logged on status. Otherwise I would need my Windows password.

Since my script is asking for a password for `laptop-ql9k5dk6\david`; I think it must be my Windows password?

So. Why does my Windows Password fail when my PowerShell one-liner (shown above) asks me for a password?

```
PowerShell credential request
Enter your credentials.
Password for user laptop-ql9k5dk6\david: **************

Get-SqlInstance: Failed to connect to server laptop-ql9k5dk6\sqlexpress2.
```

On MSSM I can also login via SQL Login but for that the username is different from the Windows Authentication user above.

Note: My current Windows password is good. I use it regularly without making mistakes/leaving CAPs on etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
$role = "sql"
$user = read-host "user for $role"
$pwd = read-host "password:" -AsSecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pwd

Get-SqlInstance -Credential $cred -ServerInstance "laptop-ql9k5dk6\sqlexpress2"
```

perhaps the cmdlet does not support Integrated Security=true;

Comment: I think you are on the right track. But your answer doesn't do it. My aim for using the `Get-SqlInstance` cmdlet was to make an initial connection to one of my SQL databases. So I am now thinking there is more to this than I first thought. For most of my databases I have been using SQL logins. So I am now looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/manage-authentication-in-database-engine-powershell?view=sql-server-ver16